# Fixed div with padding increase width

Tags: html, css

I have a simple template where I show header, content and footer section in the centre, Header has background color and all the contents should have 30px padding on left & right.

I dint it following way but it increases the width.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZapEE?editors=1100

```
html, body, form {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    height:100%;
}

body {
    font-family: "Open Sans","Trebuchet MS",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    color: #687074;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.main-wrapper{
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    height:100% !important;
    padding:0 30px;
}
.header-wrapper{
    width:100%;
    min-height:200px;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    padding:0 30px;
}
.content-main{
    width:1000px;
    min-height:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.footer-wrapper{
    width:1000px;
    min-height:200px;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
.header-row1{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
.header-col1
{
float:left;
width:132px;
width:50%;

}
.header-col2
{
 float:right;
width:50%;
}
.header-col2 > h1{
  font-size:60px;
  text-align:right;  
}
.header-logo{

}
.header-row2{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    padding:0 30px;

}
```

Comment: Try removing `width:100%;` from `.header-wrapper`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to fit it in:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

**Box-sizing values:**

> **content-box**: This is the initial and default value as specified by the CSS standard. The width and height properties are measured including only the content, but not the padding, border or margin.
>
> **border-box**: The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin.

Comment: Mozilla supports an additional padding-box value, which will cause the sizes to be applied to the padding and content, but not the border.